# Как добавить в свое расширение к браузеру (add-ons) одну "фичу" показанную на картинке?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

В *AdBlock* есть "фича" строка на иконке которая показывает количество заблокированных рекламных блоков. Я не преследую цели просто стянуть из исходника этого приложения код. В чужом коде сложно с ходу разобрать что к чему. Интересно как они туда это поместили. Может есть у кого соображения как сделать такое, а может кто предложит другой способ. Может с помощью SVG можно такое проделать, а потом ее в виде иконки поставить.

[image: AdBlock]

*Жду предложения.*

(Всплывающие окна давно не в моде.)

Comment: Вы бы сначала уточнили, эта фича сохранилась в новом FF, а то в нём сильно порезали возможноть кастомизации интерфейса

Comment: У меня на Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0 все работает

Comment: В веб-приложение — никак, эта фича доступна только расширениям

Comment: Извиняюсь, я думал расширения веб браузеров относиться к веб-приложениям т.к. они относятся к веб-программированию. Можно было и понять из контекста, изменю содержание.

Comment: API браузера нужно смотреть. В хроме для этого используется `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText`, в Firefix наверно как-то так же. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759130/google-chrome-extension-numbers-on-the-icon

Comment: Спасибо Beast Winterwolf, нашел сразу же и для FF [browser.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: (++clicks).toString()});](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText) . Еще не распробовал что и как но по Examples вроде то что надо. Других вариантов думаю нет.